# Using Vanilla Javascript to detect scroll to help make change to navigation CSS

Tags: javascript, dom

I am attempting to detect scroll on a page if it exceeds 100px from a fixed top navigation that has a height of 80px.

The plan is that once the user's scroll, exceeds the mentioned 100px, the navbar will change background color.

I have seen a lot of tutorials on the subject, but all those I have seen are using Jquery. I wish to make this using Vanilla Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use **window.onscroll** to detect scroll and **window.pageYOffset** or  **document.documentElement.scrollTop** properties to get the scroll position of window. below is a code snippet for your scenario you described:

```js
window.onscroll = function(){
var top =  window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
if (top > 100) {
 document.getElementById('nav').style.background = "blue";
} else {
 document.getElementById('nav').style.background = "yellow";
}
};
```

```css
nav {
  position:fixed;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  background:yellow;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  Hello
</nav>
<div style="height:700px;">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing this is perfect, I will practice more with this properties to get used to them for more implementations. Thanks for that.

Comment: Welcome carol Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
      // Do something
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it out thanks to you all

Answer (score 0):

Bind an event listener to window object;
`window.addEventListener("scroll", callback)`

Then on your callback you could make use of these properties/functions;

JS Scroll:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

JS Height:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/height